# What are the accumulation points of the complex sequence $i^n/n$ $(n=1,2.3,\dotsc)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I noticed that the points in the sequence are approaching $(0,0)$. Is it an accumulation point? The options for this multiple choice question are given as: 1)$\theta$, 2)$\{-1,1\}$, 3)$\{i,-i\}$ and 4)$\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is $0$, obviously, since $|i^n|=1$. So you're dealing with a complex number whose [module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) constantly decreases towards $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: thank you so much @Lucian!!